# ansible dict object has no attribute

Tags: docker, ansible

I am new here and new to ansible. I know there are several playbooks arround for what I´m doing, but so I learn better.

I try to create a docker swarm via ansible. My Problem is that I get the following error:

```
fatal: [dn12]: FAILED! => {
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'
```

I don´t understand why I get this error.
This is the output where I get the var with the Join-Token.

```
changed: [dn11] => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": "docker swarm join-token --quiet worker", 
    "delta": "0:00:00.060052", 
    "end": "2020-05-05 13:54:04.939337", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "docker swarm join-token --quiet worker", 
            "_uses_shell": true, 
            "argv": null, 
            "chdir": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "executable": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "stdin": null, 
            "stdin_add_newline": true, 
            "strip_empty_ends": true, 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "rc": 0, 
    "start": "2020-05-05 13:54:04.879285", 
    "stderr": "", 
    "stderr_lines": [], 
    "stdout": "SWMTKN-1-2g5ndm8bfe22ft9cydbl80kcxdv356jjkuyokdclnu33t7q1zg-5l9rxjpjylprqzhk5oq4165gc", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "SWMTKN-1-2g5ndm8bfe22ft9cydbl80kcxdv356jjkuyokdclnu33t7q1zg-5l9rxjpjylprqzhk5oq4165gc"
    ]
}
```

Here is the short role I run. Whats the problem. I didn`t find the error.

```
---
- block:  
  - name: Inspect docker swarm
    shell: docker info
    register: docker_info
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: Initialize Docker Swarm
    shell: >
          docker swarm init
          --advertise-addr={{ gluster_ip }}:2377
    when: "docker_info.stdout.find('Swarm: active') == -1"

  - name: Get the Manager join-token
    shell: docker swarm join-token --quiet manager
    register: manager_token

  - name: Get the worker join-token
    shell: docker swarm join-token --quiet worker
    register: worker_token
  tags:
    - createswarm
  when: inventory_hostname == swarm_master

- block:
  - name: Add Managers to the Swarm
    shell: "docker swarm join --token {{ manager_token.stdout }} {{ gluster_ip }}:2377"
    #when: "docker_info.stdout.find('Swarm: active') == -1"
  tags:
    - addtoswarm
  when: inventory_hostname != swarm_master
```

I hope you can help me find the failure.

Greats pr0

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier than expected. The problem is that the register variable applies per host.

Because the variable is only carried out on the host that is in swarm_master, the variable is only available on this.

In this case I have to use the host in swarm_master in the line where I access the variable. So the line changes as follows.

from:

```
    shell: "docker swarm join --token {{ manager_token.stdout }} {{ gluster_ip }}:2377"
```

to:

```
   shell: "docker swarm join --token {{ hostvars[swarm_master]['manager_token']['stdout'] }} {{ hostvars[swarm_master]['gluster_ip'] }}:2377"
```

Then everything goes. :-)